# Structured Concurrency difference between addTask and addTaskUnlessCancelled Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

I am have confusion between Calling `addTask()` and `addTaskUnlessCancelled`. By definition `addTask()` on your group will unconditionally add a new task to the `group`

```swift
func testCancellation() async {
    do {
        try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group -> Void in
            group.addTaskUnlessCancelled {
                print("added")
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                throw ExampleError.badURL
            }
            group.addTaskUnlessCancelled {
                print("added")
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
                print("Task is cancelled: \(Task.isCancelled)")
            }

            group.addTaskUnlessCancelled {
                print("added")
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5_000_000_000)
                print("Task is cancelled: \(Task.isCancelled)")
            }
            group.cancelAll()
            try await group.next()

        }
    } catch {
        print("Error thrown: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid adding tasks to a cancelled group, we have to use the `addTaskUnlessCancelled()` method. But even with `group.cancelAll()`, it is adding all Task to group. Then what's the difference here and returning value which return `true` only if `Task` throws some error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Short answer

The virtue of `addTaskUnlessCancelled` is that:

- it will not even start the task if the group has been canceled; and
- it allows you to add an early exit if the group has been canceled.

If you are interested, you can compare the source code for [`addTask`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/0f52bae8bc939a04eafee5fe935a5c7f7ccf20a8/stdlib/public/Concurrency/TaskGroup.swift#L226) with that of [`addTaskUnlessCancelled`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/0f52bae8bc939a04eafee5fe935a5c7f7ccf20a8/stdlib/public/Concurrency/TaskGroup.swift#L252), right below it.

---

#### Long answer

I think the problem is best exemplified if we change the task group is processing requests over time (e.g. consuming an `AsyncSequence`).

Consider the following

```swift
func a() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for await i in tickSequence() {
            group.addTask(operation: { await self.b() })

            if i == 3 {
                group.cancelAll()
            }
        }
    }
}

func b() async {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    while CACurrentMediaTime() - start < 3 { }
}

func tickSequence() -> AsyncStream<Int> {
    AsyncStream { continuation in
        Task {
            for i in 0 ..< 12 {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC / 2)

                continuation.yield(i)
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, `b` is awaiting tick sequence events, calling `c` for each one. But we cancel the group after the fourth task is added. That results in the following:

[image]

So we can see the signpost ⓢ where the group was canceled after the fourth task was added, but it proceeded unaffected.

But that is because `b` is not responding to cancelation. So let's say you fix that:

```swift
func b() async {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    while CACurrentMediaTime() - start < 3 {
        if Task.isCancelled { return }
    }
}
```

You now see behavior like the following:

[image]

That is better, as `b` is now canceling, but `a` is still attempting to add tasks to the group even though it has been canceled. And you can see that `b` is repeatedly running (though at least it is now immediately terminating) and the task initiated by `a` is not finishing in a timely manner.

However, if you use `group.addTaskUnlessCancelled` it not only will not add new tasks to the group at all (i.e., it does not rely on the cancellation capabilities of the task), but it also lets you exit when the group is canceled.

```swift
func a() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for await i in tickSequence() {
            guard group.addTaskUnlessCancelled(operation: { await self.b() })
            else { break }

            if i == 3 {
                group.cancelAll()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That results in the desired behavior:

[image]

Obviously, this is a rather contrived example, explicitly constructed to illustrate the difference, but in many cases, the difference between `addTask` and `addTaskUnlessCancelled` is less stark. But hopefully the above illustrates the difference.

Bottom line, if you might be canceling groups in the middle of adding additional tasks to that group, `addTaskUnlessCancelled` is well advised. That having been said, if you do not cancel groups (e.g., canceling tasks is more common than canceling groups, IMHO), it is not entirely clear how often `addTaskUnlessCancelled` will really be needed.

---

Note, in the above, I removed all of the `OSLog` and signpost code to generate all of the above intervals and signposts in Xcode Instruments (as I did not want to distract from the question at hand). But, if you are interested, this was the actual code:

```swift
import os.log

private let log = OSLog(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

func a() async {
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        let id = log.begin(name: #function, "begin")
        defer { log.end(name: #function, "end", id: id) }

        for await i in tickSequence() {
            guard group.addTaskUnlessCancelled(operation: { await self.b() }) else { break }

            if i == 3 {
                log.event(name: #function, "Cancel")
                group.cancelAll()
            }
        }
    }
}

func b() async {
    let id = log.begin(name: #function, "begin")
    defer { log.end(name: #function, "end", id: id) }

    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    while CACurrentMediaTime() - start < 3 {
        if Task.isCancelled { return }
    }
}

func tickSequence() -> AsyncStream<Int> {
    AsyncStream { continuation in
        Task {
            for i in 0 ..< 12 {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC / 2)

                continuation.yield(i)
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

With

```swift
extension OSLog {
    func event(name: StaticString = "Points", _ string: String) {
        os_signpost(.event, log: self, name: name, "%{public}@", string)
    }

    /// Manually begin an interval
    func begin(name: StaticString = "Intervals", _ string: String) -> OSSignpostID {
        let id = OSSignpostID(log: self)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: self, name: name, signpostID: id, "%{public}@", string)
        return id
    }

    /// Manually end an interval
    func end(name: StaticString = "Intervals", _ string: String, id: OSSignpostID) {
        os_signpost(.end, log: self, name: name, signpostID: id, "%{public}@", string)
    }

    func interval<T>(name: StaticString = "Intervals", _ string: String, block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        let id = OSSignpostID(log: self)

        os_signpost(.begin, log: self, name: name, signpostID: id, "%{public}@", string)
        defer { os_signpost(.end, log: self, name: name, signpostID: id, "%{public}@", string) }
        return try block()
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks - was trying to get my head around this too 

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this amazing response.